# span of (1,1,1) and (0,1,1) in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: vectors

what is span of (1,1,1) and (0,1,1) in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I know that these two vectors are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but what is span?

Comment: A plane. One axis vertical and another between the x and y axes.

Comment: The span is the collection of elements of the form $a(1,1,1) + b(0,1,1)$ where $a$ ande $b$ are real numbers.

Comment: which plane please give some more explanation

Answer (score 1):

The span consists of all linear combinations of (1,1,1) and (0,1,1), that is, the set of elements ($x$,$x+y$,$x+y$) for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Notice that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: yes but i am able to visualize which plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it spans